# IIS 7 Determine popular / commonly used URL

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, url, performance-counters

I'm trying to find the right performance counter in IIS 7 which would tell me what the most commonly requested URL is, but I think I may be looking in the wrong place. How would I go about finding this information short of writing custom code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance log doesn't store this information.  What you are looking for are the IIS logs, which by default may not be verbose enough for what you are trying to capture.  [Check this out](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/log).